# Problem with Embedding Layer definition in C++ (mlpack lib)

Tags: c++, armadillo, mlpack

I face the following problem. I want to build an LSTM model to make Sentiment Analysis. In C++, I use the mlpack library. Firstly, to understand the architecture I approached the problem via python and Keras advised from some tutorials. This [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-word-embedding-sentiment-classification-using-keras-b83c28087456) had this code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, GRU
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

print('Build model...')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length())
model.add(GRU(units=32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In my code, in C++, I have written this block:

```
model.Add<IdentityLayer<> >();
model.Add<Embedding<> >(vocabSize, embedSize);
model.Add<LSTM<> >(inputSize, lstmCells, maxRho);
model.Add<Dropout<> >(0.5);
model.Add<ReLULayer<> >();
model.Add<Linear<> >(lstmCells, outputSize);
```

The output console gives me this error:

```
error: conv_to(): given object can't be interpreted as a vector
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  conv_to(): given object can't be interpreted as a vector
```

I cannot understand where is the error after several hours of debugging ...
Thank you

Comment: If you run in a debugger does the debugger stop when the `std::logic_error` exception is thrown? Because in that case you could just keep going up in the stack until you find the problem in your code.

Comment: Yes, I have followed the backtrace but without positive results. Thanks for your reply.